# Is it possible to send “raw” data through a USB port at high speeds?

Tags: windows, usb

Assume that I have a custom USB3 device. Is it possible to send "raw" data, something like:

```
0x01 0x02 0x03
```

through a USB3 port connected to said device?

What protocol would I have to use? I've read up on Serial and apparently the fastest possible speed is 115200bps, or 14kbytes/sec, which is really slow.

Assuming the USB device is "fast enough" to "keep up" with my computer:

- How much data would I be able to send?
- How fast would I be able to send it?
- What would be the limitations? (i.e. USB3 speed)

Comment: Hey John D., it looks like you are asking the same question for the third time. Maybe you better explain what your real problem is, why you are so persistent? Maybe there is a different angle at your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the question literally, the answers are:

1. To communicate with "a custom USB3 device" the system must have a custom driver. The custom driver will communicate with USB3 host controller, and controller will arrange any data in proper USB format and protocol.
2. Yes, it is possible to send any data, as long as a computer application prepares them, and issues a transfer request with the data to driver. For example, for a mass storage USB device, one can create "raw" (incrementing pattern, or anything else) binary data in a file, and then drag and drop the file into USB drive.
3. Serial UART protocol has nothing to do with any USB whatsoever.
4. The amount of data depends on type of what device can consume. If this is a video streaming device, the amount of data is unlimited, you can play movie stream forever. If the device is of storage type, the amount is obviously limited to device capacity.
5. If a device is fast enough for USB3 protocol, a fast computer can deliver about 450-480 MBytes per second of data in one direction.
6. The limitation for USB3 Gen1 is the speed of the bus, which is 500 Mbytes/s minus link management and protocol overhead.